# Import MySQL dump containing CREATE DATABASE and USE to a custom database

Tags: mysql

I received a huge database dump (21 GB) including a CREATE DATABASE and USE statement.

Now I want to import that dump - but into a different database.

This is how the dump looks like (line numbers added by me)

```
17: --
18: -- Create schema foo
19: --
20:
21: CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS foo;
22: USE foo;
23:
24: --
```

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16776/how-to-change-the-create-and-use-statement-in-a-large-sql-file-without-opening-i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use head and tail to remove that part from the dump

```
head foodump.sql -n 16 > processed.sql
tail foodump.sql -n +23 >> processed.sql
```

And then import processed.sql to the database.

```
# mysql
mysql> CREATE mydatabase
mysql> exit
Bye
# mysql mydatabase < processed.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change the lines that say `Create Database` and `use`:

```
17: --
18: -- Create schema foo
19: --
20:
21: CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS foo;
22: USE foo;
23:
24: --
```

to:

```
17: --
18: -- Create schema foo
19: --
20:
21: CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS DBNAMEYOUWANT;
22: USE DBNAMEYOUWANT;
23:
24: --
```

where DBNAMEYOUWANT is the database name you want to create and do the imports to.

Additionaly you can use sed like:

```
sed -i "s/^CREATE\ DATABASE\ IF\ NOT\ EXISTS\ foo;/CREATE\ DATABASE\ IF\ NOT\ EXISTS\ DBNAMEYOUWANT;/g" /path/to/dump
sed -i "s/^USE\ foo;/USE\ DBNAMEYOUWANT;/g" /path/to/dump
```

Comment: The question is how to change that as the dump is too large for any text editor :-)

Comment: I've added a line about using sed in this case so you don't have to open the file in a text editor. This should help.

Comment: thanks :-) I think we also can combine that in one sed call .. so the huge dump does not have to be processed twice.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually remove that pair of lines and then just import it to an existing database.